# How can I check if the value of argument provided from GETOPTS is equal to specific string?

Tags: string, bash, docker, getopts

Im writing bash script which will build a docker image locally or remotely depending on the argument provided.

Im struggling with checking if the provided string is equal to "remote" or "local".

When I execute script, it doesn't accept any number, but it does accept any string.

```
!/bin/bash

usage() { echo "Usage: $0 [-m < local|remote>]" 1>&2; exit 1; }

while getopts "m:" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        m)
            destination=${OPTARG}
            ((destination == "local" || destination == "remote")) || usage
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done
shift "$((OPTIND-1))"

echo $destination
```

Comment: Someone commented a while ago how you should NOT use getopts and instead use just normal parameter parsing MOST of the time. I cant find the exact link which highlighted the reasons now but maybe thats the right approach here.

Comment: `(( ))` is for arithmetic operation use `[[ "$destionation" = local || "$destination" = remote ]] ` for string comparison

Comment: [[ "$destionation" = local || "$destination" = remote ]] adding those helped me in some way. Now script is accepting only second value which currently is "remote" but unfortunately it doesnt accept first one "local", or "localy" or whatever else I call it. It returns output of usage().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So really the only change you need to make is to change your `((...))` statement to a `[[ ... ]]` statement as @Nahuel Fouilleul suggested and add `$`'s to your destination variables. Their suggestion didn't work for you however because destination was spelled wrong. I have the updated code shown below.

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() { echo "Usage: $0 [-m < local|remote>]" 1>&2; exit 1; }

while getopts "m:" o; do
  case "${o}" in
    m)
        destination=${OPTARG}
        [[ $destination == "local" || $destination == "remote" ]] || usage
        ;;
    *)
        usage
        ;;
  esac
done

shift "$(( OPTIND-1 ))"

echo $destination
```

However, you don't need to check for this information in the switch statement, you could do a check in the main part of your code and ensure that destination has been set using parameter expansion as I show here:

```
...
    m)
        destination=${OPTARG}
        ;;
...

[[ ${destination:?A destination is required.} == "local" || ${destination} == "remote" ]] || usage

echo $destination
```

Comment: You've helped me a lot! Before I had checked my code for missing characters or wrong spellings, but I didn't notice that mistake when I was copying part of that code...
Much appreciated, cheers!